# how to put take form input and save it in a table in localstorage

Tags: javascript, html

So I've been trying my hands at HTML and JS and I created a form that stores data in a table, but whenever I refresh all inputted data goes away. I want to be able to take the input from the form and place it in the table and put the table in a localstorage so the data remains permanently.

code so far
**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-Edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> Financial Records </title>
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.9/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/3.5.6/jspdf.plugin.autotable.min.js"></script>   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">  
    <style> h1 { text-align: left; font-family: Poppins-SemiBold; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px;} </style>
<style> 
        .specialtext {
          width: 300px;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
          border-radius: 4px;
          font-size: 16px;
          background-color: white;
          background-position: 10px 10px; 
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          padding: 12px;
        }
</style>
<style>
  label{
    float:left;
  }
</style>
<style>
  :root {
  --main-color: #3d5af1;
  --main-color-dark: #3651d4;
  --main-color-light: #5872f5;
  --text-color: black;
}
</style>
<style>
  @font-face {
    font-family: Poppins-SemiBold;
    src: url(Poppins-SemiBold.ttf);
  }
</style>
<style> 
    input[type=number] {
      width: 250px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: 1px solid rgb(5, 5, 5);
      border-radius: 4px;
      font-size: 16px;
      background-color: white;
      background-position: 10px 10px; 
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
    }
</style>
<style>
    input[type=date] {
        width: 150px;
        height: 40px;
        border: 1px solid rgb(5, 5, 5);
      border-radius: 4px;
    }
</style>
<style>
  .button1 {
    background-color: var(--main-color);
    border: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bolder;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 20px;
  }
  
  .button1:hover {
    background-color: #d1dbec;
  }
  .button2 {
    background-color: var(--main-color);
    border: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bolder;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 20px;
  }
  
  .button2:hover {
    background-color: #d1dbec;
  }
  
  .button3 {
    background-color: rgb(255, 70, 70);
    border: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bolder;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 20px;
  }
  
  .button3:hover {
    background-color: #d1dbec;
  }
  
</style>
<style>
  table {
    font-family: Poppins-SemiBold, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width:100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
   
  td, th {
    border: 1px solid #050505;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 12px;
    width: 10%;
  }
  
  tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #a9e3fa;
  }
</style>
<style>
  form {
 border: 1px solid white;
 border-radius: 5px;
 width: 730px;
 background-color: white;
}
</style>
<style>
.card {
  display: flex;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 5px lightgray;
  transition: 1s;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  }  
</style>
<style>
  .main{
    background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
  }
</style>
<style>
  .container {
  padding: 5px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="sidebar-top">
      <span class="shrink-btn">
        <i class='bx bx-chevron-left'></i>
      </span>
      <img src="./img/aces4.png" class="logo" alt="">
      <h3 class="hide">ACES DBMS</h3>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="sidebar-links">
      <ul>
        <div class="active-tab"></div>
        <li class="tooltip-element" data-tooltip="0">
          <a href="#" data-active="0">
            <div class="icon">
              <i class='bx bx-tachometer'></i>
              <i class='bx bxs-tachometer'></i>
            </div>
            <span class="link hide">Dashboard</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="tooltip-element" data-tooltip="1">
          <a href="finance.html" class="active" data-active="1">
            <div class="icon">
              <i class='bx bx-dollar-circle'></i>
              <i class='bx bxs-dollar-circle'></i>
            </div>
            <span class="link hide">Finance</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="tooltip-element" data-tooltip="2">
          <a href="members.html" data-active="2">
            <div class="icon">
              <i class='bx bx-user'></i>
              <i class='bx bxs-user'></i>
            </div>
            <span class="link hide">Members</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="tooltip-element" data-tooltip="3">
          <a href="evangelism.html" data-active="3">
            <div class="icon">
              <i class='bx bx-user-plus'></i>
              <i class='bx bxs-user-plus'></i>
            </div>
            <span class="link hide">Evangelism</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="tooltip-element" data-tooltip="4">
          <a href="inventory.html" data-active="4">
            <div class="icon">
              <i class='bx bx-book'></i>
              <i class='bx bxs-book'></i>
            </div>
            <span class="link hide">Inventory</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="tooltip-element" data-tooltip="5">
          <a href="calendar.html" data-active="5">
            <div class="icon">
              <i class='bx bx-calendar'></i>
              <i class='bx bxs-calendar'></i>
            </div>
            <span class="link hide">Calendar</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="tooltip-element" data-tooltip="6">
          <a href="attendance.html" data-active="6">
            <div class="icon">
              <i class='bx bx-bar-chart-square'></i>
              <i class='bx bxs-bar-chart-square'></i>
            </div>
            <span class="link hide">Attendance</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="tooltip-element" data-tooltip="7">
          <a href="#" data-active="7">
            <div class="icon">
              <i class='bx bx-church'></i>
              <i class='bx bxs-church'></i>
            </div>
            <span class="link hide">Service Schedule</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="tooltip-element" data-tooltip="8">
          <a href="login.html" data-active="8">
            <div class="icon">
              <i class='bx bx-log-out'></i>
              <i class='bx bxs-log-out'></i>
            </div>
            <span class="link hide">Log Out</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <div class="tooltip">
          <span class="show">Dashboard</span>
          <span>Finance</span>
          <span>Members</span>
          <span>Evangelism</span>          
          <span>Inventory</span>
          <span>Calendar</span>
          <span>Attendance</span>
          <span>Service Schedule</span>
          <span>Log Out</span>
        </div>
      </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="main">
    <h1> Financial Records </h1>
    <input type="text" id="search" class="specialtext" onkeyup="searchFunction()" placeholder="Search by monetary type...">
    <br>
    <br> 
    <div class="card">
    <form id="financialRecordsForm">  
        <label for="date"><p>Date: </p></label> <br/> 
       <input type="date" id="date" name="todaysdate"/> <br/>  
    <br>
      <label for="moneytype"><p>Monetary Type: </p></label> <br/>
      <select id="moneytype" class="specialtext">
        <option disabled selected hidden>Choose</option> 
        <option>Offering</option>
        <option>Tithe</option>
        <option>Donation</option>
        </select>
      <br><br>
      <label for="servicename"><p>Total Amount Received: </p></label> <br/> 
      <input id="servicename" type="number" placeholder="Enter amount in cedis" data-date-inline-picker="true" />
      <br><br>
      <label for="amtreceived"><p>Service Name: </p></label> <br/> 
      <input id="amtreceived" type="text" class="specialtext" data-date-inline-picker="true" />
      <br><br><br>
</span>  
</form> 
</div>
<button class= button1 onclick="addNew()" id="addbutton"><b>ADD</b></button> 
<button class= button2 onclick="reset()"><b>RESET</b></button>  
<script>
  function addNew() {
    var enter = document.getElementById("date");
    localStorage.setItem ("date", enter.value);
}
</script>
<script>
    function reset() {
    document.getElementById("financialRecordsForm").reset();
    }
</script>
<div class="card">
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Monetary Type</th>
        <th>Service Name</th>
        <th>Total Amount Received</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
</table>
</div>
<button class="button3" value="EXPORT TO PDF" id="pdf" onclick="downloadPDFWithjsPDF()">EXPORT TO PDF</button>
  
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    document.getElementById("addbutton").onclick=function()
    {
        document.getElementById("table").style.display="block";
        
        var table = document.getElementById("table");
        var row = table.insertRow(1);
        var date = row.insertCell(0);
        var moneytype = row.insertCell(1);
        var amtreceived = row.insertCell(2);
        var servicename = row.insertCell(3);
        var deleterow = row.insertCell(4);
        date.innerHTML = document.getElementById("date").value;
        moneytype.innerHTML = document.getElementById("moneytype").value;
        amtreceived.innerHTML = document.getElementById("amtreceived").value;
        servicename.innerHTML = document.getElementById("servicename").value
        deleterow.innerHTML = '<input id="deleterow" type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/>'
        
        return false;
    }
    
    function searchFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("search");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("table");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
function deleteRow(btn) {
  var row = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
  row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
}
function downloadPDFWithjsPDF() {
  var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');  
    var htmlstring = '';  
    var tempVarToCheckPageHeight = 0;  
    var pageHeight = 0;  
    pageHeight = doc.internal.pageSize.height;  
    specialElementHandlers = {  
        // element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector  
        '#bypassme': function(element, renderer) {  
            // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"  
            return true  
        }  
    };  
    margins = {  
        top: 150,  
        bottom: 60,  
        left: 40,  
        right: 40,  
        width: 600  
    };
    var y = 20;  
    doc.setLineWidth(2);  
    doc.text(200, y = y + 30, "FINANCIAL RECORDS", );  
    doc.autoTable({  
        html: '#table',  
        startY: 70,  
        theme: 'grid',  
        columnStyles: {  
            0: {  
                cellWidth: 100,
            },  
            1: {  
                cellWidth: 100,  
            },  
            2: {  
                cellWidth: 100,  
            },
        },  
        styles: {  
            minCellHeight: 20  
        },
        styles: {  
            halign: 'center'  
        },
    })  
    doc.save('Financial Records');  
  }
</script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not be permanently storing sensitive user data in `localStorage`.

An alternative is `sessionStorage` or `document.cookie`.

But let me show you how to use localStorage and sessionStorage first.

#### LocalStorage

###### Syntax

```js
localStorage; // Storage { ... }
```

Unlike sessionStorage, localStorage has *no* expiration.
But with sessionStorage, you can't store nearly the amount of data size as cookies or localStorage. The sessionStorage also only lasts unless the page is gone (history deletion, window/tab closed, etc.) but not page refreshes.

#### SessionStorage

###### Syntax

```js
sessionStorage; // Storage { ... }
```

As I said, sessionStorage is just like localStorage except it only lasts the page's session (history deletion, window/tab closed, etc.). With sessionStorage, you can only store 5kB of data. With localStorage, you can store up to 5MB of data!

#### Cookies

###### Syntax

```js
document.cookie; // "cookie1=something; cookie2=something;"
```

There are many Libraries (such as [Cookie.js](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)) and APIs for cookies (for setting, getting, and deleting cookies) that make it easier.

But there's still ways to do this without a library.
Here's some examples:

```js
// Set/Replace a cookie
document.cookie = "cookie1=something;Expires=;path=/";
```

You may notice a message:

> The operation is insecure.

Stackoverflow does not allow cookies/storage to be set for security reasons.
Try it only your local webserver and it'll work.

Here is some more code that lets you do way more than just setting cookies:

##### Setting cookies

```js
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  const d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
  let expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function set() {
  setCookie("cookie1", "something", 30);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="set()">Create Cookie</button>
```

##### Getting cookies

```js
function getCookie(cname) {
  let name = cname + "=";
  let decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  let ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(let i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
    let c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}

function get() {
  console.log(getCookie("cookie1"));
}
```

```html
<button onclick="get()">Get cookie</button>
```

*More about cookies at https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp.*

---

#### Back to localStorage

If you still want to use localStorage, here is some code for what you're looking for.

```js
// Storage.prototype.setItem (set an item)
localStorage.setItem("item","value");

// The quick way
localStorage["item"] = "value";

// Storage.prototype.getItem (get an item)
localStorage.getItem("item"); // "value"

// The quick way
localStorage["item"]; // "value"
```

More about `Storage` at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage.